# Aptana : java was started by returned exit code=13

Tags: aptana

windows 8.1 64 Bit , Aptana 3.4.2 , Java 64 Bit

Error:

[image]

Java :
[image]

Answer (score 51):

Must you have 32-bit version of java, or may be you have both version [32-bit 64-bit] of java on same computer. 
Make sure you have 32-bit version then must you specify the version that using in Aptana studio to do this : 
1-Go to apatana folder and find the AptanaStudio3.ini file 
 
      "C:\Users\[YourUser]\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio"

[image]

2- Add the java 32-bit version path to AptanaStudio3.ini using notepad

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solves the same issue for Appcelerator Studio also.

Comment: Thanks! I only had to install the JRE 32 birts in mi PC and ready. Of course I installed at the default directory. My PC has W10.

Comment: Great, this fixed it for me, thanks for the screenshots it makes it easy

Comment: Sidenote: It doesn't have to be an JDK, the JRE installation works too (as long as it's 32bit).

Answer (score 32):

Package arch is 32-bit only for Windows OS. The 32-bit version of the JDK is required regardless of whether it is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows system. You can download [here from the official website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: So the "x64 Compatible" advertised on the Aptana download page is only referring to ability to run on the operating system?  All 32-bit apps run on 64-bit Windows, so claiming compatibility with 64-bit is very misleading.  It sounds like a 64-bit Java compatibility.

Comment: Aptana may be x64 compatible, but it requires JRE 32 bit.

Comment: Understood.  It appears the SWT is the underlying thing that's 32-bit that limits choice of JVM.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same error but I was on Windows 10 64-bit, Aptana 3.6.1, with only 64-bit JDKs.

After I downloaded 32-bit 1.7 JDK, I was able to open and run Aptana just fine.

[image]

I didn't need to modify the .ini file as AbuSitta had suggested.

I'll agree it might be misleading to some if you don't take a sharper look and see the "*x86, x64*" description at the download page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Windows OS, Aptana Only runs using Java 32 bit (JRE or JDK)

Answer (score 0):

Am I late to the party ? Just started on ruby yesterday..and this was the recommended IDE in 3 of the 4 tutorials i saw..Spent the whole day trying to configure this.

Aptana Studio needs 32 bit jdk to be installed even on a 64 bit processor.. The "compatibility" suggested  is a bit misleading..I just had to install the 32 bit jdk.. Did not modify the .ini file as @Osama Abusitta said. Just restarted the pc post installation for the effect to take place.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Same Error. just install **Java jdk.1.8 x86** (32bit) Version.

[image]

modify the .ini file

C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\AptanaStudio3.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\javaw.exe
-name
Aptana Studio 3
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved changing the path inside the Aptana icon with:
"C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\AptanaStudio3.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre-1.8\bin\javaw.exe"
P.S. I don't have a .ini file in AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\ folder