# When running Eclipse: java was started by returned exit code=13

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to download Eclipse to start making some apps.  I downloaded the launcher from:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

I then moved the Eclipse file over to program x86.
I also updated the Eclipse file so that it changes the directory where it finds my JRE file.  I will attach the file code I have so far.

Eclipse and Java are both 64

Any help will be amazing!

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166795/eclipse-crashes-at-startup-exit-code-13

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan I have looked at that multiple times.  Can't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: You are using a 64 bit Eclipse with a 32 bit Java. You must run all 64 bit or all 32 bit. The Java is in `Program Files (x86)` which makes it 32 bit unless your install is very broken.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you post your eclipse.ini file?**

It may just be the way the error shows (and not how it is written in the eclipse.ini file), but there is text in [Eclipse.ini (Specifying the JVM)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) that says the following:

> - The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
> - The value must be the full absolute path to the Java executable, not    just to the Java home directory.
> - The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything    after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM

Answer (score 0):

@Developer SuRu it is right
And this link explain easily how can do this
[Java was started but returned exit code=13 [FIXED]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uptr8VKq-eQ)

Or see this Answer :
[Add the java 32-bit version path to AptanaStudio3.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590850/aptana-java-was-started-by-returned-exit-code-13/31355286#31355286)